# Get the instantly added element in PHP $HTTP_POST_VARS

Tags: php, forms, http-post, preg-match, http-post-vars

I am working on a webpage which needed to get the field value by matching the field name in the form.

The field's name are in the pattern abc_1, abc_2, abc_3...
Everything are working well in the beginning. The fields with those name can be matched in the below method. But the problem comes when the user instantly create the field with the field name (example: abc_4)

By using the below method, the http_post_vars method cannot get the new added element.

Is there any way to refresh the page or any method that can solve my problem.
Thanks for you help...

```
foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) {

if (preg_match('/^abc_([0-9]+)$/', $key, $matches)) {  
....

}
```

here is the way how I dynamic generate the field

```
function addNewPiForm() {
                  piSize++;

                  $('#piList').append('<li id="piId' + piSize + '">'+ piSize +'.&nbsp;<input type="text" size="40" name="abc_' + piSize + '" />}
```

I have checked the name in a browser spect mode. The values are correct

Here is the coding how I submit

```
if (tep_not_null($action)) {
switch ($action) {
  case 'update':    
    foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'abc_4' )
        {
            die();      
        }
        if (preg_match('/^abc_([0-9]+)$/', $key, $matches)) {  
            //die();        
            $abc = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['abc_' . $matches[1]]);
            .....
```

Comment: anyone please help..

Comment: this part is in the update $action.
Will it be any concern?

Comment: How are you submitting those values to the server? Dynamically adding a field will submit the field name and value with the rest of the form. Are you adding it outside of the form tag? 

One observation: $_HTTP_POST_VARS was deprecated a very long time ago. Any reason you're not just justing $_POST? See docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply first
I am using a old php server so HTTP_POST_VARS is still work for me in this case
I have checked the field name after the foreach statement by using the following 
    foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) {
   if ($key == 'abc_4' )
   {
    die();
   }

No field with the name can enter the foreach statement
I submit the form by the action "update"

Comment: I have updated the coding in the question. Please have a look...
Thanks